# Python nested loop to identify characters in string of text

Tags: python

I have a string of text that reads:

```
1x2xx1x2xx1x2xx1x2xxx
```

I need to take apart the string of text, and if it is a number, i want to pass that number along with a few other variables to another function to print a square on a canvas.

I wrote the following code:

```
def process_single_line(a_canvas, line_of_pattern, left, top, size):
    x = left
    y = top

    for char in line_of_pattern:
        if char.isdigit():
            type_of_tile = int(char)
            draw_tile (a_canvas, type_of_tile, x, y, size)
        else:
            x += size
```

The issue I am having is:

1. It doesn't seem to work, the rectangles and shapes that `draw_tile`
   is supposed to print don't appear (but the `draw_tile` function
   works fine, because it is being referenced multiple times else where
   in the program where it prints just perfect)
2. At the end of the loop I want to increase the y value by y+=size as
   well, so that when the NEXT string of text is passed through the
   function it moves to the NEXT grid line.

Expected Outcome:
[image]

What I am getting vs What I am trying to get:

[image]

Comment: Your `type_of_tile` parameter is going to be a string, because you are taking letters (even if the letters look like "1", "2", etc.) from the string. Does the `draw_tile` function expect a string, or actual numbers? Try `int(type_of_tile)` maybe?

Comment: Please update your question with the expected output of `1x2xx1x2xx1x2xx1x2xxx` so we can understand what you want

Comment: @AustinHastings you're right, I had to change it to `int`.

Comment: @cricket_007 updated it. I made the change to `int` as per suggested by Austin, but my result isn't quite matching up as expected:

Comment: Ah, the pentomino problem... Okay, can you explain then what the line of input means, then in simple terms? Like you see a 1 followed by an x, means draw...???

Comment: `1x2xx1x2xx1x2xx1x2xxx` means that a tile of Type 1, followed by one grid space which does not require any tile drawing, followed by a tile of Type 2, followed by 2 grid spaces which does not require tile drawing, followed by a tile of Type 1, followed by one grid space which does not require any tile drawing, followed by a tile of Type 2, followed by 2 grid spaces which do not require tile drawing, followed by a tile of Type 1, so on.

Comment: The types of tiles and their "respective" drawings have already been defined in `draw_tile()` function.

Comment: Is `size` the size of a single "square"?

Comment: `size` refers to the size of a single grid square

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you should always increment the x position after rendering.

try this:

```
def process_single_line(a_canvas, line_of_pattern, left, top, size):
    x = left
    y = top

    for char in line_of_pattern:
        if char.isdigit():
            type_of_tile = int(char)
            draw_tile (a_canvas, type_of_tile, x, y, size)

        x += size
```

Answer (score 2):

Multiline solution (in case you didn't have it)

```
def process_single_line(a_canvas, line_of_pattern, left, top, size):
    x = left
    y = top

    for char in line_of_pattern:
        if char.isdigit():
            type_of_tile = int(char)
            draw_tile(a_canvas, type_of_tile, x, y, size)

        x += size


lines = ['1x2xx1x2xx1x2xx1x2xxx', '3xxxx3xxxx3xxxx3xxxx']
for line_num, line in enumerate(lines):
    process_single_line(canvas, line, 0, size*line_num, size)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.